# I saw the cat being struck by

Tags: meaning

What's the difference? Are my ideas in the parentheses correct?

> 1 I saw the cat struck by a car. (I didn't see the moment when it was
> struck)
>
> 2 I saw the cat being struck by a car. (I saw the moment when it was
> struck)
>
> 3 I saw that the cat had been struck by a car. (I saw the
> consequences)
>
> 4 I saw that the cat was struck by a car. (????)

Comment: I probably wouldn't say "being struck" because *striking* something is instantaneous. If I wanted a progressive aspect, I would probably say "being run over"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The distinction here is between vagueness and precision. 1 and 4 are vague, 2 and 3 precise.

Option 1, using the [preterite / simple past / past indefinite tense](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_past) is vague. It could mean "I saw the cat [which had been] struck by a car" or "I saw the cat [as it was being] struck by a car". The idea in parentheses only covers one of these, but we don't have sufficient information to tell from the sentence which was intended.

2 ([present participle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Participle#Forms)) and 3 ([past perfect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_(grammar))) are precise, and the ideas in parentheses are accurate.

4 is also vague. The [imperfect past progressive / past continuous](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Imperfect) tense of "was struck" doesn't help us, and we would want some additional context, for example :

> I was walking along the street and I saw that the cat was struck by a
> car (suggests seeing the event)
>
> I was examining the pet and I saw that the cat was struck by a car
> (suggests seeing consequences)

Comment: Good answer. There is one point which seems to me debatable, nonetheless. If I said "I saw a car fixed by Jack", I think, it would be hard to interpret it as "I saw a car as it was being fixed by Jack". Or is it a possible interpretation? It's just that it resembles "I saw the cat struck by a car." and I find it hard to make out "I saw the cat [as it was being] struck by a car"

Comment: "I saw a car fixed by Jack" could be a passive construction of "I saw Jack fix a car"  - it's valid but less common and might seem odd (though similarly "I saw a car Jack had fixed" would be more precise for the other meaning). Thanks for accepting the answer - I usually leave that for a day or so in case something better comes along rather than deselecting one and picking the other, but I won't be offended if that happens.

Comment: It's also a distinction between literal and metaphorical senses of "[see](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/see)": it can mean to perceive through your eyes, or to realise, discover, come to know, or deduce, as well as other perhaps less relevant meanings such as to make sure, accompany, or prefer.

Comment: @StuartF - Good point. I'd probably try to jam it in as an edit if we were on ELU, though it complicates things by not fitting a 1,4/2,3 split. I'll happily upvote it if it appears as another answer.

Comment: To my mind, the most natural usage of "I saw that the cat was struck by a car" would be (e.g.) "I was reading the newspaper yesterday and there was a story about how a cat had been run over".

Comment: And that's the importance of context. @avid. When I read the OP statement, I immediately understood that they saw the moment when the cat was hit by the car. I might even have said it that way, but with hit rather than struck.

Comment: Funny thing, "I was walking along the street and I saw that the cat was struck by a car (suggests seeing the event)" does not actually suggest that to me. Instead it suggests that the cat is laying on the side of the road either injured or dead. Once again, the vagaries of the English language rear their ugly head.